# Setting onClick of dynamic elements generated through document.createelement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set onClick function of dynamic generated elements. The function has to set state.

```
var root = document.getElementById("results_container");
var title = document.createElement('a'); 
title.setAttribute("id", 'title');
title.onclick = function () {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
}.bind(this)
```

I am getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined and I am assuming that onclick function is unable to reach this.state. Please help

Comment: Okay. What's your question?

Comment: @bejado edited my question

Comment: I still don't see a question. Come back when you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @bejado I am getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined and I am assuming that onclick function is unable to reach this.state.

Comment: I'm not sure what `this.state` is supposed to be or where it is defined, so I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery function `on`. It binds the action even in newly generated element.

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
    // statement here
})
```

For your reference: [jQuery .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` variable is undefined... If you are using react, you need to store the reference to the component instance (`this`) somewhere, and pass that to your bind function. This is probably a very poor way to do this, however. If you are using react, you likely want something more like this:

```
class Results extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <a onClick={()=>this.setState({isOpen:!this.state.isOpen})}>
        Title  
      </a>
      {this.state.isOpen ? this.getOpenContent() : null}
    </div>;
  }
  getOpenContent() {
    return <div> ... </div>;
  } 
}
```